# Output key value pairs as JSON from T-SQL query

Tags: json, t-sql

I have an app that needs to be supplied with configuration data as key value pairs in JSON.

I want to output JSON of key value pairs from a table query.

The table can have different named items and varying quanities of items.

TABLE

| ITEMID | REPORTID | NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29 | caption | Profit by Product |
| 2 | 29 | bgColor | #FFFFFF |
| 3 | 29 | showBorder | 0 |
| 4 | 29 | showsum | 0 |

SQL

```
select .................   FOR JSON PATH
```

I'm guessing this needs to use a PIVOT?

Expected JSON

```
{"caption":"Profit by Product","bgColor":"#FFFFFF","showBorder":"0","showsum":"0"}
```

Appreciate help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 3):

Your can do a little String Aggregation  (assuming not 2017)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ITEMID] varchar(50),[REPORTID] varchar(50),[NAME] varchar(50),[VALUE] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,29,'caption','Profit by Product')
,(2,29,'bgColor','#FFFFFF')
,(3,29,'showBorder','0')
,(4,29,'showsum','0')


Select REPORTID
      ,JSONString =  '{' + Stuff((Select concat(',','"',Name,'":"',value,'"') From @YourTable Where ReportID=A.ReportID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')  + '}'
 From @YourTable A
 Group by REPORTID
```

**Returns**

```
REPORTID    JSONString
29          {"caption":"Profit by Product","bgColor":"#FFFFFF","showBorder":"0","showsum":"0"}
```

Comment: Great, +1 from my side. I think it's worth to mention, that using `For XML Path (''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')` would avoid unescaped XML entities.

Answer (score 2):

A pivot query along with `FOR JSON PATH` should generate the JSON output you expect:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'caption' THEN VALUE END) AS caption,
    MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'bgColor' THEN VALUE END) AS bgColor,
    MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'showBorder' THEN VALUE END) AS showBorder,
    MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'showsum' THEN VALUE END) AS showsum
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ITEMID
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that if your table contains more than one `ITEMID` group, then there would be one JSON record in the output per item.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this needs to be flexible and the key value pairs can change / have different number.

Comment: This is the best answer of which I know given the sample data you actually showed us.  If my answer falls short for a certain use case, then provide data for that case.

Comment: I have changed the question, apologies for not being clear.

Comment: I don't know of a way to handle your requirement other than by having generic key names, such as `key1`, `key2`, etc.  Would that be acceptable to you?

Comment: There are hundreds of potential keys, so I'm hoping for something flexible rather than using rigid fields.

Comment: There is probably a way to do this via dynamic SQL, but that is beyond my grade `:-(`

Comment: "beyond my grade"  I actually laughed out loud.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but having this question myself I wondered if there was another way.  And found one - using the quirky update behaviour of SQL server to perform a custom aggregation using the [MODIFY_JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function in SQL 2016:

```
go
create or alter function getSourceAsJson(@id int) returns nvarchar(max) as
begin
    declare @j nvarchar(max) = '{}'

    select @j = JSON_MODIFY(@j, '$.' + [name], [value]) 
    from SourceTable
    where Id = @id

    return @j
end
go

select dbo.getSourceAsJson(1) as Json
```